# How can you detect when "break" is called in the callers Proc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a library that iterates over a set and calls the caller's proc for every item in the set. Example:

```
def self.each(&block)
    # ... load some data into results_array
    results_array.each do |result|
        status = block.call(result)
        # how do I know to call break if the user calls break?
        break if status == false
    end
end
```

Currently, as you can see in my code, I inspect the "last expression evaluated" in order to break.  This seems bug-prone as the end-user may have a perfectly valid reason for their last expression evaluating to false. The more appropriate thing would be to detect the caller using "break".

How do I know to call break if the user calls break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `yield` instead of `block.call`, you can use the difference in behavior between `next` and `break`. As an example:

```
def each(&block)
  puts "before"
  result = yield
  puts "after"

  result
end

each do
  puts "hello"
  next
end

# Result:
#   before
#   hello
#   after

each do
  puts "hello"
  break
end

# Result:
#   before
#   hello
```

As you can see, when you use `next` inside a block, the control is given back to the function calling the block. If you use `break` however, the calling function will return immediately with `nil` as a return value. You could now exploit this behavior with some trick:

```
def each(&block)
  # ...

  results_array.each do |result|
    block_result = yielder(result, &block) || {:status => :break, :value => nil}
    if block_result[:status] == :break
      # block has called break
      #...
    else
      # block has called either next or the block has finished normally
      #...
    end
  end
end

def yielder(*args, &block)
  value = yield *args
  {:status => :normal, :value => value}
end
```

This works because here, the `yielder` function returns either `nil` in case the `block` called `break` or a hash with a status and the return value of the block. You can thus differentiate between a valid result (which is always different from `nil`) and an exceptional result which is always `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, unless I don't understand what you are trying to do:

```
def each(&block)
  # ... load some data into results_array
  results_array= [1, 2, 3]
  results_array.each do |result|
    block.call(result)
  end
end


each do |result|
  puts result
  break
end
```